# Git, как правильно скопировать чужой проект в свой?

Tags: git, github

Есть мой проект с какими-то моими наработками. Есть [проект слайдера](https://github.com/kopipejst/coin-slider) на github.com. Хочу скопировать его правильно к себе в проект.

Я мог бы просто взять и скачать его с сайта и мне бы этого было вполне достаточно. Но все же мне хочется узнать, что я потеряю в данном случаи, какие у меня будут преимущества?

Еще хочу, если это возможно и не долго, сделать так, чтобы у этого скопированного слайдера был только один последний коммит.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8 `git submodule add https://github.com/kopipejst/coin-slider.git coin-slider`

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо за полезную инфу. Жаль, что я раньше не нашел этот учебник. Изучал [вот этот](https://githowto.com/ru), а там я не чего подобного не припоминаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить этот проект как *субмодуль* в ваш проект. Синаксис такой:

```
git submodule add <откуда> <в какую папку>
```

В данном случае:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:kopipejst/coin-slider.git coin-slider
```

Такой способ позволит вам впоследствии обновлять библиотеку с гитхаба:

```
cd coin-slider
git pull
```

Про это:

> если это возможно и не долго, сделать так, чтобы у этого скопированного слайдера был только один последний коммит

В рабочей области проекта (т.е. на диске) будет лежать последний коммит ветки `master`. Все остальные тоже будут доступны, как в любом другом репозитории.

Comment: Спасибо, за информацию!))) Единственное, ваш варит не сработал: "fatal: не удалось клонировать «git@github.com:kopipejst/coin-slider.git» в подмодуль по пути «/srv/http/test»". Побывал по проще, так сработало!) git submodule add https://github.com/kopipejst/coin-slider.git Поправите меня, если так делать нельзя.

Comment: @taiiku наверное, нужно чтобы папка `/srv/http/` существовала и у вас были права на запись в неё. Она точно не руту принадлежит?

Comment: **http** - принадлежит мне, но почему-то переименовать не могу, (заметил случайно, хотел скопировать имя), а вот svr - это **root**.  Попробовал создать тестовый репозиторий в **домашней папке**, та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone
```

И создастся папка с именем репозитория

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть на лицензию проекта. Судя по всему лицензия проекта [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) - одна из самых либеральных, следовательно вам нет необходимости отдельно публиковать модификации, которые вы возможно будете вносить. Следовательно нет необходимости заморачиваться с fork'ом проекта.

В таком случае достаточно будет дернуть [zip архив](https://github.com/kopipejst/coin-slider/archive/master.zip) и вставить его в свой проект (лучше всего в отдельный каталог).

Минусом такого подхода будет то что при модификации исходного проекта вам придется вручную мержить изменения в проекте. Но вам это скорее всего не грозит, так как последние коммиты были 4 года назад.

Comment: Спасибо, за хорошее объяснения ситуации и про лицензии.