# Как скопировать содержимое двух репозиториев в один?

Tags: html, css, git, github

Репо №1: стандартная директория для старта проекта( https://github.com/beast1/start-project )

Репо №2: библиотека миксинов( https://github.com/beast1/scss-mixins )

Репо №3: абстрактный новый проект, куда нужно скопировать содержимое двух предыдущих

Как сделать так чтобы содержимое первых двух репозиториев оказались в третьем?

Comment: например, можно просто скопировать в один каталог нужные файлы/каталоги и сделать это репозиторием (`git init; git add .; git commit`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека миксинов выглядит как зависимость (dependency, ресурс, библиотека), а [зависимости нужно изолировать от кода приложения](https://12factor.net/ru/dependencies), подключая их с помощью менеджера зависимостей.

Похоже, что в проекте уже используется менеджер зависимостей [Bower](https://bower.io/), его конфигурация лежит в файле `.bowerrc`. Используйте его, чтобы подключить миксины к проекту. Наверняка нужно просто указать папку, в которой они лежат.

В файловой системе репозиторий с миксинами может лежать совсем отдельно, а может быть [субмодулем git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621277/181472) внутри репозитория с проектом.

В процессе разработки вы сможете работать с каждым репозиторием отдельно:

- Папку с репозиторием проекта можно просто копировать в новое место, в ней останется git-репозиторий.
  Создайте новый проект на GitHub и перенастройке на него свой локальный репозиторий.
  Подробная инструкция — [здесь, после заголовка «Как копировать проект локально и на гитхабе»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658632/181472).
- Если вы захотите как-то доработать миксины, сохраняйте изменения именно в репозиторий с миксинами. Тогда вы сможете легко использовать их в другом проекте.

А объединять два репозитория в один попросту не нужно. Аналогично, если сегодня вы решите покататься на велосипеде в любимых штанах, вы не обязаны приклеивать штаны к велосипеду.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите **сохранить их историю***, можно загрузить оба репозитория в новый и сделать самое обычное слияние (merge) их веток в вашу новую:

В вашем новом репозитории (или в пустой папке, сделав `git init`):

```
git remote add репо-А git@github.com:юзер/репо-А.git
git remote add репо-Б git@github.com:юзер/репо-Б.git
```

Затягиваем их содержимое:

```
git fetch репо-А
git fetch репо-Б
```

При загрузке каждого репозитория, история которого не пересекается с вашей, выведется предупреждение о том, что этот репозиторий никак к новому не относится.

> warning: no common commits

Часто это означает, что вы делаете что-то не так, например перепутали адрес репозитория и загрузили коммиты не туда, куда хотели. Но сейчас нам именно это и нужно.

А теперь к делу. Соединяем текущую ветку и ветку из добавленных репозиториев:

```
git merge репо-А/ветка
git merge репо-Б/ветка
```

Кириллические идентификаторы заменить по всему усмотрению.

Видно, что строки повторяются для каждого добавляемого репозитория. То есть, да, таким способом можно смешать сколько угодно репозиториев.

---

** которой у вас всё равно нет, но мало ли кто ещё будет искать ответ на этот вопрос*

Comment: Плюс за предусмотрительную инструкцию и интересный метод. Но в данном случае я думаю, что репозитории вообще не нужно объединять.